# How to build a solution with 2 main class (with only one running at one time) calling to one global java file

Tags: java, jar, build

Good day to all,
 I need advice on the best way to build a solution for the following scenario.

a) In one project, I have two main class files, `A.java` and `B.java`. There is another file,
   `C.java`, which will be called by `A.java` or `B.java` respectively. At any 
    one time, only `A.java` or `B.java` can be run. `C.java` contain a function which will pass value to `A.java` or `B.java`, depending which file is being executed. `C.java` can be considered as a global file to both `A.java` and `B.java`

b) For example, if `A.java` is being executed, it will call to `C.java` to pass some values back to `A.java`.

Hope to have advice on what is the best way to build this solution so that a user can either run `A.java` or `B.java` at will, while calling to the global `C.java`

Thank you. Feel free to let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Is there any more context you can give to the specific question?

Comment: You should have `A` or `B` inject itself into `C` or register a callback with `C`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one of the cleanest ways to do this is to create a pair of executable jars each with a manifest specifying which class is the main class.  Using ant  you might specify two targets for your build 'a' and 'b' as so.  A full example below, the key here is again specifying what is main the in manifest and having ant just build you two executable.  Not very size efficient, but quite explicit way of doing what you want to do.

```
<project name="a_or_b" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="deploy.dir"     value="bin"/>

    <property name="main-class-a"  value="package.a.mainclass"/>
    <property name="main-class-b"  value="package.b.mainclass"/>


    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${deploy.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" debug="on" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar-a" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}-a.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class-a}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="jar-b" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}-b.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class-b}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="jar-a,jar-b"/>

    <target name="deploy" depends="clean,jar">
        <mkdir dir="${deploy.dir}"/>
        <copy todir="${deploy.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${jar.dir}"/>
  </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,jar,deploy"/>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class `Main.java` which will contain the only main method in the project. Remove main methods from `A.java` and `B.java`. `Main.java` will call either `A.java` or `B.java` based on command line arguments. User can handle which one to run from command line.